# JQbootstrapvailadtion (or any other validation package) not working with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, validation

I am currently looking for a validation method for Meteor and have tried both Parsley.js and jqbootstrapvalidation with the same result. I have added both of the packages but my forms do not seem to use either for validation, instead they show (what I believe to be) the standard meteor "this field is required" pop up.

I have tried

```
        <input type="email" class="form-control validated" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required />
```

with

```
 Template.createQuiz.rendered = function () {
$(function(){$(".validated").jqBootstrapValidation();});

}
```

And pure html

```
     <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group warning">
        <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" aria-invalid="true">
            <p class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li>Not a valid email address<!-- data-validator-validemail-message to override --></li></ul></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Test Validation <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></button></div></form>
```

Does anyone have a working example or a tip to get validation with either jqbootstrap or parsley.js working? Much appreciated

Edit:

For parsley I have tried

```
<form id="demo-form parsley" data-parsley-validate>

  <!-- this field is just required, it would be validated on form submit -->
  <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" required />

  <!-- this required field must be an email, and validation will be run on
  field change -->
  <label for="email">Email * :</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" required />

  <!-- radio and checkbox inputs by default have to be wrapped in a parent
  elemnt (here <p>) that will have success and error classes -->
  <label for="gender">Gender *:</label>
  <p>
    M: <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" value="M" required />
    F: <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" value="F" />
  </p>

  <!-- here, field is not required, it won't throw any error if no checkbox
  is checked. But if checked, two at least must be checked -->
   <label for="hobbies">Hobbies (2 minimum):</label>
   <p>
Skiing <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="ski" data-parsley-mincheck="2" />
Running <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="run" />
Eating <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="eat" />
Sleeping <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="sleep" />
Reading <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="read" />
Coding <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="code" />
```

```
<label for="heard">Heard us by *:</label>
   <select id="heard" required>
<option value="">Choose..</option>
<option value="press">Press</option>
<option value="net">Internet</option>
<option value="mouth">Word of mouth</option>
<option value="other">Other..</option>
```

```
  <!-- this optional textarea have a length validator that would be checked on keyup after 10 first characters, with a custom message only for minlength validator -->
  <label for="message">Message (20 chars min, 100 max) :</label>
  <textarea name="message" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-length="[20, 100]" data-parsley-validation-threshold="10" data-parsley-minlength-message = "Come on! You need to enter at least a 20 caracters long comment.."></textarea>

  <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

And then:

```
Template.createQuiz.rendered = function () {
    $("#parsley").parsley();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootstrap control group **and** initialize the validation inside your rendered function.

**Template**

```
<template name="createQuiz">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" class="form-control validated" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required />
        <p class="help-block"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

**Code**

```
Template.createQuiz.rendered = function () {
  $(".validated").jqBootstrapValidation();
};
```

Comment: thanks! that works, Would you know how I  show the user all the errors on the page simulataneously? As in the main example at http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Answer (score 0):

It is almost same response for parsley.js, you just need to add it to the rendered function

```
Template.createQuiz.rendered = function () {
    $('#yourFormId').parsley();
}
```

Of course you need to add necessary attributes to your form elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited original post to reflect my attempt for parsley. Your suggestion does not seem to work. Could you check what I am doing wrong would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try removing data-parsley-validate from <form id="demo-form parsley" data-parsley-validate> form element. You should also fix formid

Comment: I have removed the demo-form s an id and removed data-parsley-validate but the form just gives the standard meteor this field is required pop up instead of the nice summary and visual effect of http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html.

Comment: I think form id and the id you use in rendered function don't match. Make sure form id and id in rendered function match. That id should also be unique

Comment: What do you mean? the form id is form id="parsley" the rendered is Template.createQuiz.rendered = function () {
    $("#parsley").parsley();
}; Both are parsley right or am I missing something really obious

Comment: That seems right. Do you have any error messages on browser console?